# Jumping/Glitching component data | Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to enter two different types of datasets. The first is a list of machinery and the second is a list of raw materials. I have a main component that is defined as follows:

**Main Component**

```
<div>
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="table-area mb-4">
            <div class="table-row">
                <div class="fw-bold p-2 border">
                    Machinery
                </div>
                <div class="fw-bold p-2 border border-start-0">
                    Supplier
                </div>
                <div class="fw-bold p-2 border border-start-0">
                    Place of origin
                </div>
            </div>
            @foreach ($machineries as $machinery)
                <livewire:machinery-component :machineryId="$machinery->id" :key="$machinery->id">
            @endforeach
            <div class="table-row">
                <div class="p-2 border border-top-0">
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add machinery here" wire:model='machinery_name'>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2 border border-top-0 border-start-0">
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add supplier here" wire:model='machinery_supplier'>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2 border border-top-0 border-start-0">
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add origin here" wire:model='machinery_origin'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-primary mb-5" wire:click.prevent='addMachinery'>Add Machinery</div>

        <div class="table-area mb-4">
            <div class="table-row">
                <div class="fw-bold p-2 border">
                    Machinery
                </div>
                <div class="fw-bold p-2 border border-start-0">
                    Supplier
                </div>
                <div class="fw-bold p-2 border border-start-0">
                    Place of origin
                </div>
            </div>
            @foreach ($materials as $material)
                <livewire:materials-component :materialId="$material->id" :key="$material->id">
            @endforeach
            <div class="table-row">
                <div class="p-2 border border-top-0">
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add raw material here" wire:model='materials_name'>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2 border border-top-0 border-start-0">
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add supplier here" wire:model='materials_supplier'>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2 border border-top-0 border-start-0">
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add origin here" wire:model='materials_origin'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-primary mb-5" wire:click.prevent='addRawMaterial'>Add Raw Materials</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
use App\Models\Machinery;
use App\Models\RawMaterial;
use Livewire\Component;

class Main extends Component
{
    public $machinery_name;
    public $machinery_supplier;
    public $machinery_origin;
    public $materials_name;
    public $materials_supplier;
    public $materials_origin;

    public $listeners = ['deleteMachinery', 'deleteMaterial'];

    public function addMachinery(){
        Machinery::create([
            'name' => $this->machinery_name,
            'supplier' => $this->machinery_supplier,
            'origin' => $this->machinery_origin
        ]);

        $this->machinery_name = '';
        $this->machinery_supplier = '';
        $this->machinery_origin = '';
    }

    public function deleteMachinery($id) {
        Machinery::where('id', $id)->delete();
    }

    public function addRawMaterial(){
        RawMaterial::create([
            'name' => $this->materials_name,
            'supplier' => $this->materials_supplier,
            'origin' => $this->materials_origin
        ]);

        $this->materials_name = '';
        $this->materials_supplier = '';
        $this->materials_origin = '';
    }

    public function deleteMaterial($id) {
        RawMaterial::where('id', $id)->delete();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.main',[
            'machineries' => Machinery::all(),
            'materials' => RawMaterial::all(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then I have components for the two datasets. These are being used to display the data fetched from the
database. Here is how each of them is defined:

**Machinery Blade**

```
<div>
    <div class="table-row position-relative">
        <div class="p-2 border border-top-0">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add raw machinery here" wire:model='name'>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 border border-top-0 border-start-0">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add supplier here" wire:model='supplier'>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 border border-top-0 border-start-0">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add origin here" wire:model='origin'>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-box position-absolute end-0">
            <div class="btn text-danger" wire:click='delete({{$machineryId}})'>
                <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Machinery Controller**

```
class MachineryComponent extends Component
{
    public $machineryId;
    public $name;
    public $supplier;
    public $origin;

    public $listeners = ['updateMachinery'];

    public function mount() {
        $machinery = Machinery::where('id', $this->machineryId)->first();

        $this->name = $machinery->name;
        $this->supplier = $machinery->supplier;
        $this->origin = $machinery->origin;
    }

    public function updateMachinery() {
        $machinery = Machinery::where('id', $this->machineryId)->first();

        $machinery->name = $this->name;
        $machinery->supplier = $this->supplier;
        $machinery->origin = $this->origin;
        $machinery->save();
    }

    public function delete() {
        $this->emitUp('deleteMachinery', $this->machineryId);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.machinery-component');
    }
}
```

**Materials Blade**

```
<div>
    <div class="table-row position-relative">
        <div class="p-2 border border-top-0">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add raw material here" wire:model='name'>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 border border-top-0 border-start-0">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add supplier here" wire:model='supplier'>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 border border-top-0 border-start-0">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add origin here" wire:model='origin'>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-box position-absolute end-0">
            <div class="btn text-danger" wire:click='delete({{$materialId}})'>
                <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Materials Controller**

```
    public $materialId;
    public $name;
    public $supplier;
    public $origin;

    public $listeners = ['updateMaterial'];

    public function mount() {
        $material = RawMaterial::where('id', $this->materialId)->first();

        $this->name = $material->name;
        $this->supplier = $material->supplier;
        $this->origin = $material->origin;
    }

    public function updateMaterial() {
        $material = RawMaterial::where('id', $this->materialId)->first();

        $material->name = $this->name;
        $material->supplier = $this->supplier;
        $material->origin = $this->origin;
        $material->save();
    }

    public function delete() {
        $this->emitUp('deleteMaterials', $this->materialId);
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.materials-component');
    }
```

Now when ever I try to enter machinery, if the materials table has entries, they move from being displayed in the materials table and appear in the machinery table and I am unable to run any function when that happens. Refer to the images below:

**Before data entry**
[Editable entries taken from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JISA1.png)

**Attempt to add new entry**
[Editable entries taken from the database on attempt to add add new entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgkhG.png)

I want the fields rendering the values from the database to be editable. When I render the data as static data, there is no error happening but the moment I use the components, the code breaks. I do not want to have the data be static as I want to be able to make corrections to previous data without having to delete and start afresh. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume machinery can have same id as material. Since both components use id as key, a situation where both components have the same key "1" is possible.

In Livewire it's important to always ensure all child components have unique key.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components

An easy fix to avoid collisions is to add some string in front of key, like "machinery-" for example.

For example:

```html
<livewire:machinery-component wire:key="machinery-{{ $machinery->id }}">
```

and

```html
<livewire:materials-component wire:key="material-{{ $material->id }}">
```

This way keys will be machinery-1, material-1, machinery-2, material-2 and so on

Comment: This has been really helpful. Solved my problem actually. Much appreciated

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. I've run into these problems many times and they can be difficult to notice. My personal opinion is that livewire should check this and throw a warning or something.